# Replace 0 value with Null in Spark dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Actually I am trying to write Spark Dataframe to Json format. I want to avoid 0 value attribute in json dump therefore trying to set the value in all columns with zero value to None/NULL.

Note: Since I am using pivot method to dynamically create columns, I cannot do with at each columns level.

```
+----------------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+     
|ID                |T1             |T2        |T3          |T4           |T5                 |DT             |         
+----------------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+     
|929916248484355237|0.000000       |0.0       |0E-10       |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|772216248474350399|0.880000       |0.0       |1.4808200000|0E-10        |2.36082             |20220916120738|         
|772216248474350399|0.000000       |0.0       |0E-10       |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|075616248464351729|0.010000       |0.0       |0.0127000000|0E-10        |0.022699999999999998|20220916120738|         
|915716248424355578|0.010000       |0.0       |0.0127000000|0E-10        |0.022699999999999998|20220916120738|         
|277016248484357606|0.000000       |0.0       |0E-10       |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|739516248574350647|0.000000       |0.0       |0E-10       |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|915716248424355578|0.000000       |0.0       |0E-10       |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|075616248464351729|0.000000       |0.0       |0E-10       |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|756216248594352650|0.000000       |0.0       |0E-10       |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
+----------------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+----------------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+     
|ID                |T1             |T2        |T3          |T4           |T5                  |DT             |         
+----------------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+     
|929916248484355237|null           |0.0       |null        |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|772216248474350399|0.880000       |0.0       |1.4808200000|null         |2.36082             |20220916120738|         
|772216248474350399|null           |0.0       |null        |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|075616248464351729|0.010000       |0.0       |0.0127000000|null         |0.022699999999999998|20220916120738|         
|915716248424355578|0.010000       |0.0       |0.0127000000|null         |0.022699999999999998|20220916120738|         
|277016248484357606|null           |0.0       |null        |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|739516248574350647|null           |0.0       |null        |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|915716248424355578|null           |0.0       |null        |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|075616248464351729|null           |0.0       |null        |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
|756216248594352650|null           |0.0       |null        |20.0000000000|20.0                |20220916120738|         
+----------------------+---------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

I tried with this and it returns as expected

```
cols = [when(~col(x).isin(0), col(x)).alias(x) for x in df.columns]
df = df.select(*cols)
```

Any other best approach is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use `ds.na().fill(0)`? This will fill any null value in all columns with `0` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `replace` function

```
df.replace(0.0, None)
```